# How to share a D8 configuration without the UUID limitation?

Tags: 8

How can I share a Drupal 8 configuration (content type, custom view/menu/block, etc.) with another website without the UUID limitation?

Each site has a unique UUID, and refuses to work with the configuration file of another website. It's a big problem that doesn't allow users to share their configuration with the world.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use [the features module](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) which is pretty stable and useful. You can even bundle specific configs and install them later on any website as a module (thus not needing to install the module there).

Comment: Using Features is my recommendation as well since it now does only what it was always meant to do, and builds on CMI. Also note that single import/export has less strict validation and this is currently a concern that needs to be addressed in core. For dev purposes, you can also leverage `drush devel-generate-uuid` to generate UUIDs on the fly. Supposedly that should never be happening but in dev, who knows?

Answer (score 0):

The [Configuration Development](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_devel) module allows you to export configuration that can be shared/re-installed by stripping out the UUID for you. Unlike features, you have to manually manage the config you want to export by listing them in your module info yml file.