# Error while importing just exported content type with drupal console

Tags: 8, nodes, console

I'm trying to export a content type from one drupal installation and then install it to another.

I export a content type with :

```
 ../vendor/bin/drupal cect
```

And then I try to import it to another drupal installation like this:

```
../vendor/bin/drupal ci --directory modules/custom/custom_module/config/optional/
```

This gives me the following error :

```
[ERROR] An error occurred while trying to write the config file: "Site UUID in source storage does not match the target
     storage.
     The core.extension configuration does not exist.
     Can not uninstall the Configuration module as part of a configuration synchronization through the user
     interface."
```

I thought it was just something with the other sites UUID but I get the same error if I try to import it into the site that I exported it from.

Comment: Try remove UUID in export file and try again. AS UUID differs in both sites.

Comment: @AAjayReddy i tried it and it didn't work, thanks for the answer though

Comment: You can't do an export from one site into a different site without stripping out UUID and a couple other identifiers. If this is the route you want to take, you should look at Features, which is what that was designed for. Otherwise, you could run a script over that config directory to strip out the things that will prevent import. See: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/177139/how-to-share-a-d8-configuration-without-the-uuid-limitation