# Ignore UUIDs when comparing the difference between configuration exports

Tags: 8, features

When building [Features](https://drupal.org/project/features), i find it useful to keep a 'backup' of the full configuration and commit it to version control.

If something breaks when i package a feature after i test how it works by doing a full re-install of the profile that brings together the feature modules, i can restore things i missed from the configuration export.

Unfortunately, every site install produces different UUIDs in every configuration file, so i cannot use a diff to determine if there are missing or unexpected changes in the site-install version of the configuration i packaged up.  Drush does not have [an export option to strip UUIDs on export](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2642398).

In the past we used a script to delete all the UUID lines, but not being built into Drush, it was Python or Bash i think, it was awkward to use.  But if i find it i'll post it.

How can i get a clean diff of changes that filters out the noise of the UUID changes?

Comment: Meant to mention, related but not the same as my goals here, https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/177139/how-to-share-a-d8-configuration-without-the-uuid-limitation

Comment: FYI: Since v8.6.0 there is now an explicit flag `drush site:install --existing-config`, which ignores the existing/mismatching UUIDs. This way you can an existing foreign site, without the content.

Comment: @Hudri yep, well aware of it, and we were doing the same thing by some trickery in custom profiles for regular sitebuilding even before https://www.drupal.org/project/config_installer came along.  The use case here is quite different: building Features, so repeatedly re-installing normally (not from the exported config), but wanting to export the config and compare exports as a check on our Feature packaging skills.

Would still really prefer just a drush config export command that would skip the UUIDs  :-/

Answer (score 4):

For that interim step, when you just need to glance over the changes in your exported config, `git diff -I"^uuid: " -- config/sync` will return a succinct list that ignores the changes in any line starting with 'uuid: '.

from the doc page on [Git-diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt--Iltregexgt):

```
-I<regex>
--ignore-matching-lines=<regex>

    Ignore changes whose all lines match <regex>. This option may be specified more than once.
```

### but wait... there's more!

The deluxe version of this command ALSO filters out file deletions & the config_hash, making the diff up to 76.3% more succinct (heh) -- all for FREE:

```
git diff -I"^uuid: " -I"config_hash" --diff-filter=MRC -- config/sync
```

And here's [the doc reference for `--diff-filter`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203):

> --diff-filter=[(A|C|D|M|R|T|U|X|B)…​[*]]
> Select only files that are Added (A), Copied (C), Deleted (D), Modified (M), Renamed (R), have their type [...]

Answer (score 1):

The use case in question here is for building features; the `config/sync` directory is never used to import, but it can be used to check if the result of a `site install` is about what we expect (and to copy wanted files or changes we wanted to keep, and missed, from a saved version).

The meaningless UUID changes in every file, however, make it impossible to find that information in all the noise.

Here is a workaround that presumes you are using Git for version control, exporting configuration and committing it, then running a site install, and re-exporting the configuration (but not yet committing it):

```
git diff -G '^[^u]*([^u][^i][^d][^:]).*'
```

will show only files with non-uuid changes. If there's a change to a uuid other than the one for the configuration as a whole (that is, indented under some other part of the configuration), that will be shown.

Super unsure about the regex in this but it's not had a false negative or positive yet.

Here's what i have in my .bashrc to make this easier to use:

```
# Diff that ignores config files whose only change is the UUID (ignores lines
# starting with 'uuid:' and probably other stuff but it's solid so far.)
alias gdu="git diff -G '^[^u]*([^u][^i][^d][^:]).*'"
```

Took me forever to come up with this workaround; hope it helps others.